# Unique List Permission During Form Submit

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, permissions

I have a SharePoint list that is populated via an InfoPath form. There are two groups of people who have access to the form: end users and owners. While I don't have any issue with assingning permissions to owners, for the end users, this proposition has been tricky.

My requirement is such that - the end users should be able to:

1. Add new items to the list via InfoPath form
2. Not interact with the list in any other way

Now if I give the end users contribute permission to the list, they will be able to view and edit other list items in the list (which is the function of owners only). But if I don't give the end users contribute permission, they cannot add to the list. Is this a real catch-22 or am I spawning this out of my ignorance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to site collection level >> Site Settings >> Site Permissions (under Users and Permissions) >> Permission Levels (under Manage section) >> Add Permission Level.

In this page, find List Permissions in Permissions section. Check "Add Items".

Create a group that you need and give it the Add Items permissions. Add all the users to this group who should only be able to add to the list and not edit it. Give the list unique permission (don't inherit form the parent). Then add the group to the list.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a custom web service that performs the task of inserting items. But the real query is - would you want them to view the items as well?

If yes, you can give the view permissions on the list to your end users and addition via your InfoPath form, which would essentially call a web service and execute the code to submit items with correct privileges.

Regards,
Nitin Rastogi

Comment: Nitin, Thank you for your feedback. What you are suggesting is a viable option. I have found an easier option it seems. I checked to see what permission I can add at the site collection level and it turns out that SharePoint allows Add Item permission, which is essentially what I needed. Thank you for your feedback though.

Comment: I am glad you found the suggestion useful. The option you chose is a good one as well. I guess probably simpler as you can just create your own permission level and assign to the user. Just for design awareness - The permission level you are planning will not have Add Item Permissions and hence the user / group wouldn't have rights on any of the list. Another option would be to create a permission level without add and only for the list in case, you assign the permission level to the user / group.